# STContains - tests failing for points INSIDE polygon

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeography

First, SQL version:

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) Apr 29 2016 23:23:58 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

I declare a single closed polygon (correctly oriented using left-hand rule), which according to SQL is valid:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-141.251221 60.177476, -134.351807 52.952478, -124.859620 48.440718, -123.623658 48.163009, -123.132020 48.232578, -122.906113 48.998367, -95.169068 48.966372, -94.980927 49.021337, -94.627991 48.700606, -93.907013 48.594450, -93.845215 48.495351, -93.510132 48.517642, -93.197022 48.583549, -92.743836 48.507408, -92.422486 48.211991, -91.573792 48.021520, -90.973664 48.095065, -90.146256 48.021693, -89.428711 47.911409, -88.442688 48.232120, -84.935303 46.850463, -84.819947 46.614678, -84.531556 46.397991, -84.200593 46.493917, -84.117508 46.124608, -83.620034 45.782175, -82.591267 45.290317, -82.166749 43.592965, -82.661133 42.606311, -82.886353 42.391659, -83.097840 42.332805, -83.187104 42.071357, -83.135605 41.842088, -82.865410 41.657411, -82.463379 41.587347, -81.068116 42.119252, -80.049134 42.334835, -78.887330 42.783953, -78.868104 42.953046, -78.995820 43.161758, -79.090577 43.433616, -78.664856 43.557148, -76.766968 43.541223, -76.398926 44.064539, -74.852601 44.971250, -71.471558 44.957647, -70.846711 45.205884, -70.589219 45.379779, -70.207787 45.900179, -69.238587 47.291005, -68.891488 47.116066, -68.297196 47.291936, -67.850361 47.016678, -67.864953 45.667941, -65.966034 43.191802, -49.229737 45.124550, -59.425049 68.026407, -75.421143 74.789051, -73.663331 78.324047, -57.315674 82.569900, -71.378174 83.545629, -112.335206 79.852216, -141.163331 70.394745, -141.251221 60.177476 ))', 4326);
SELECT @g.IsValidDetailed() AS 'IsValidDetailed', @g.STIsClosed() AS 'STIsClosed', @g.EnvelopeAngle() AS 'EnvelopeAngle';
```

When the above query is executed, SQL responds with:

```
IsValidDetailed STIsClosed  EnvelopeAngle
24400: Valid    True        33.0780372828377
```

For visual verification, I plotted the polygon (via Google maps) and also included 3 points INSIDE the polygon, as well as 3 points OUTSIDE the polygon.  Below is a screen snapshot of the polygon and points at a zoom level that shows the full polygon (the red area denotes the "bounds" that enclose the polygon):

[image: Polygon on map]

Zooming in on the map, you can start to see the individual points, i.e.:

[image: Points inside and outside of polygon]

Zooming in further, you can see two of the points are very close to the edge of the polygon, one inside (green), one outside (red):

[image: Points near edge of polygon]

The following query was used to test for points that are INSIDE the polygon:

```
SELECT lat, lon, 
       @g.STContains( geography::Point( lat, lon, 4326 ) ) AS STContains,
       geography::Point( lat, lon, 4326 ).STWithin( @g ) AS STWithin
 FROM ( VALUES ( 49.119404, -102.988586 ),
               ( 49.004776, -102.996875 ),
               ( 48.975416, -103.005152 )
       ) points( lat, lon )
```

SQL responds with:

```
lat         lon         STContains  STWithin
49.119404   -102.988586 False       False
49.004776   -102.996875 False       False
48.975416   -103.005152 False       False
```

-- Was expecting STContains and STwithin to return "True" for points inside the polygon???

The following query was used to test for the points OUTSIDE of the polygon:

```
SELECT lat, lon, 
       @g.STContains( geography::Point( lat, lon, 4326 ) ) AS STContains,
       geography::Point( lat, lon, 4326 ).STWithin( @g ) AS STWithin
 FROM ( VALUES ( 48.975409, -103.005151 ),
               ( 48.974153, -103.005144 ),
               ( 48.951739, -103.005627 )
       ) points( lat, lon )
```

SQL responds with:

```
lat         lon         STContains  STWithin
48.975409   -103.005151 False       False
48.974153   -103.005144 False       False
48.951739   -103.005627 False       False
```

-- Expected results as all points are OUTSIDE of the polygon.

**Question**:

Why is STContains / STWithin failing for points that are INSIDE the polygon?

I must assume I am doing something wrong, but I have followed the rules (left-hand) for constructing the polygon and SQL indicates the polygon is "valid".

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're using left-hand orientation? Do your expected results change if you `SET @g = @g.ReorientObject()` first?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Using the EnvelopeAngle as a heuristic, I'd expect it to be closer to (if not exactly) 180° if it were oriented incorrectly. In other news, Canada is *big*.

Comment: What does `@g.STDistance( geography::Point( lat, lon, 4326 ))` return for both the set of points that you expect to be in the polygon and those outside?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Yes, I have checked envelope angle (< 180) and also: g.STArea() < g.ReorientObject().STArea()

Comment: @BenThul - I would expect the distance from g.EnvelopeCenter for the inside points to be less than the distance for the outside points, ie: g.EnvelopeCenter().STDistance( geography::Point( lat, lon, 4326 )) AS STDistance -- tried that and confirmed - the distance for the inside points are all less than the distance of the outside points.  Still no answer as to why STContains / STWithin is failing for inside points.

Comment: I'm not asking about the distance to the envelope center, but rather distance from the point to the polygon. If they're truly inside, I'd expect a distance of zero. It could be that the ones that you expect to be inside have a very small distance to your polygon.

Comment: @BenThul Sorry, I don't understand your comment "distance from point to polygon.".  To calculate a distance one obviously needs two points.  Are you referring to a point on the edge of the polygon?, a point within the polygon? I selected the center point of the polygon and all tests passed in that the distance from the center of the polygon to any point within the polygon was less than the distance from the center of the polygon to any point outside of the polygon.

Comment: "To calculate a distance one obviously needs two points." _Au contraire_. While you can measure distance between two points, measuring distance between two arbitrary objects has just as much meaning. In your case, it means the shortest distance between the point and all points in the polygon. Which, conveniently, is what I think `STDistance()` does. The example given in the documentation has it measuring distance between a line and a point even!

Comment: @BenThul - Ah thanks -- however...
STDistance also seems to fail - Regina, SK (is INSIDE the polygon) - shows Distance of zero:
SELECT geography::Point( 50.44609833063177, -104.61851168432615, 4326 ).STDistance( @g ) AS STDistance = 0

116 km south -- still WELL INSIDE the polygon, is Weyburn, SK:
SELECT geography::Point( 49.667922159371074, -103.85796595373533, 4326 ).STDistance( @g ) AS STDistance = 3387.28093070478
-- does NOT show zero?

-- Back to the drawing board.

Comment: My rationale in asking the question was more to see if there was some dirtiness in your data. Given that the 49th parallel defines a lot of the southern border of Canada, I'd question the source of your shape data for the Canadian landmass at this point.

Comment: The polygon was plotted by hand (counter-clockwise) and then the points were plotted via google maps.   All tools I have access to indicate the polygon (shape) is correct with respect to using it with SQL geography methods.  If anyone has any (free / online) tools that they recommend for checking correctness, please feel free to chim in -- at this point, I have lost faith - in myself mainly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in spherical geometry, lines of latitude are not straight lines.  Great circle arcs are.  The nearest edge of your polygon is `-122.906113 48.998367, -95.169068 48.966372`, which is well north of the 49th parallel at -103 longitude.

```
select geography::STLineFromText('LINESTRING(-122.906113 48.998367, -95.169068 48.966372)', 4326);
```

is

[image]

Comment: Mr. Browne - once again you come through!!   So how do we "adjust" to use a Mercator projection with the SQL geography types so that points that fall inside the polygon as shown visually on a Bing or Google map?    Also -- had there been a way to show BOTH the polygon and point in the Spatial View on SSMS -- the "answer" would have been obvious.   Any way to show BOTH a polygon and a point in Spatial View?

Comment: I tried everything I could think of to display both, before hitting on just plotting the nearest edge.  Perhaps a SSMS feedback item:  https://aka.ms/sqlfeedback.

Comment: Already done -- a simple change to the Spatial View that would allow us to select multiple columns for display (rather than a single column as is currently implemented) would be a VERY welcome feature.  Thanks again !!