# SQL Server 2016 - Updating microsoft.sqlserver.types

Tags: sql-server, spatial, sqlgeography

Currently using SQL Server 2016:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) Apr 29 2016 23:23:58 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

I check to see what version of microsoft.sqlserver.types is installed, as follows:

```
SELECT clr_name FROM sys.assemblies

microsoft.sqlserver.types, version=13.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorarchitecture=msil
```

I also check using:

```
SELECT assembly_qualified_name FROM sys.assembly_types

assembly_qualified_name
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId, Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry, Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography, Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
```

According to the [NuGet Gallery for Microsoft.SqlServer.Types](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types), the current version is: 14.0.1016.290

**Questions:**

1. What is the difference between microsoft.sqlserver.types, version=13.0.0.0 shown in sys.assemblies and Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0 in sys.assembly_types?
2. Should I download and install the latest Microsoft.SqlServer.Types from NuGet on the SQL Server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you still using the RTM release? What do you have against patching, and why use a version with known security flaws? SP1 was released in November 2016, and SP2 in September 2018; you've literally had years to install them.

Comment: Because I just inherited this project -- which is hosted via a third party -- hence, I was checking for latest versions, etc.   So what you are saying, is I should contact the hosting company and ask them to update / patch - correct?

Comment: They should have updated their version some time ago, yes. That doesn't address the question, but certainly patching is something they should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I download and install the latest Microsoft.SqlServer.Types from NuGet on the SQL Server?

No.  You can't do that.  The versions that are inside the SQL Server engine are part of the product, and are updated as part of SQL Server.  You can use the newer ones in client applciations.

Comment: Thanks David!  Nice to have someone from Microsoft answer the question -- I have one outstanding if you are interested, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61734711/stcontains-tests-failing-for-points-inside-polygon